# How to get categorized laravel eloquent results based on "enum" column and show them in one page?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'll explain a pseudo situation for simplicity :

There is a `users` table:

```
id  |  name  |  status
-----------------------
```

`status` colum is `enum` and can have 3 different values: `dead`,`sick`,`healthy`

Now I want to show all `users` in one page:
`dead` users on top, `sick` users in the middle and `healthy` users at the bottom!

Do I have to execute three queries? And pass them one by one to view?
 like this :

```
$dead = User::where('status','dead')->get();
$sick = User::where('status','sick')->get();
$healthy = User::where('status','healthy')->get();
```

Or there is a better way?  what if there are 10 statuses? or 100?

**Update:**

I am looking for query performance.

Comment: So, if there are many results you are using pagination or not ?

Comment: @SagarGautam, Actually I didn't think of that! but in my situation the results are used for slides, and are not many!   For pagination it's better to send each to a different page I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby) function

```
$users = User::get()->groupBy('status');
```

The result will be like

```
[
    'dead' => [
        //items of dead type
    ],
    'healthy' => [
                   //items of healthy type
    ],
    'sick' => [
                   //items of sick type
    ]
]
```

You can access type of data like:

```
$users['dead'];
```

Comment: Then how to use the results seperated in blade file?

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to convert them to array ?  Let my try

Comment: Actually no, it will give you collection in group without `toArray()` good luck